# How to test Android App on Chromebook in kiosk mode

Tags: android, google-chrome-os, kiosk-mode

I'm testing Android App on Chromebook Acer CB3-431
I can run the app in a regular session without any problem. But the customers are complaining about the App running in Kiosk mode. They are using this approach https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7358722?hl=en to install the App.
Question: Is there a way for me to run the debug app in Kiosk mode.

Answer (score 1):

The only option for managed devices (that you cannot put in Dev mode) is to install application through the Play Store.

You can use internal app sharing to install a debug build of your application. [Here is a video](https://youtu.be/_o_q6hatcIs?t=364) that explains what is Internal App Sharing and how you can use to test an application.
You've to setup the play console to be able to use it. You can take a look at the [documentation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9303479?hl=en-GB) for more information.